# Using stat_bin_hex to plot number of levels of a factor instead of number of individual observations

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'd like make a hexagonal heatmap, but instead of showing the number of individual observations in each hexagon, I'd like to show the number of levels of a specific factor with observations in each hexagon.

I have data for two continuous variables in a number of different species. An example dataset:

```
library(dplyr)

set.seed(123)
df <- tibble(species = factor(1:10)) %>%
  group_by(species) %>%
  summarise(var1 = rnorm(100), var2 = rnorm(100))
```

The following produces a standard hexagon plot:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(x = var1, y = var2)) +
  stat_bin_hex(aes(fill = after_stat(count)))
```

[image: normal hexagon plot]

How can I show the number of species represented in each hexagon (i.e., unique levels of the factor species) instead of the overall number of observations? Based on the documentation for `stat_bin_hex()` and `stat_bin2d` I suspect I somehow need to use the factor species in `after_stat()`, but I can't figure out how to. This seems like a basic problem, I must be overlooking something. Simply mapping species to the fill scale doesn't work. I am using ggplot version 3.4.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for `stat_summary_hex`:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(x = var1, y = var2, z = species, group = 1)) +
  stat_summary_hex(fun = ~ length(unique(.x)))
```

[image]